# Wicket ajax call from client causes error

Tags: jquery, ajax, wicket, wicket-6

After a time expires, my client wants us to prompt the user for a possible keepalive to the server. I put an AbstractAjaxBehavior in place, passed the URL to the client and issue the ajax request thusly:

```
Wicket.Ajax.ajax({u: document._sessionKeepAliveUrl});
```

The URL in the value there is:

```
./.?3-1.IBehaviorListener.0-
```

A breakpoint tells me the onrequest of the behavior is invoked.  But then I get the following error on the client side:

```
Wicket.Ajax:  Wicket.Ajax.Call.failure: Error while parsing response: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getElementsByTagName')
```

So the solution mostly works. The behavior doesn't do anything with the response. What am I doing wrong. Note, this is Wicket 6 (our client doesn't want to pay for the time to upgrade since they haven't decided on our next framework).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `"wr": false` to the attributes:

```
Wicket.Ajax.ajax({u: document._sessionKeepAliveUrl, "wr": false});
```

`wr` stands for "is Wicket Response" [1]. It tells Wicket Ajax/JS whether it should try to interpret the Ajax response or not.

By default Wicket.Ajax.get/post() deals with XML response generated by AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior, but in your case you use its parent - AbstractAjaxBehavior, that may produce any kind of response, or even no response as in your case.

1. https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/3a1a614c1bce68f5eb4e62ae064b48c7bca508df/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/ajax/attributes/AjaxAttributeName.java#L69

Comment: Perfect.  Exactly what I needed.  I didn't know where those attributes were documented.

Comment: The documentation is at https://nightlies.apache.org/wicket/guide/9.x/single.html#_ajax_request_attributes_and_call_listeners